# Ensuring all Linux system threads run on core 0

Tags: linux, cpu, scheduling, multicore

I want to ensure that all system threads in Linux run on core 0, leaving all the other cores to my application. I am using RHEL 6 and I have added the following lines at the top of /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit:

```
taskset -p 0x01 1
taskset -p 0x01 2
taskset -p 0x01 $$
```

I still see a lot of threads/processes with PPID 2 running on cores other than 0. This indicates that `kthreadd` (the process with PID 2) spawns others before the above statements are executed. How can I ensure that all children of process 2 also run of core 0?

Edit: Here are, for example, the threads on core 4. Can any of these be moved away from core 4?

```
~> ps -L -eo pid,ppid,tid,nlwp,tty,comm,psr | grep 4$
  PID  PPID   TID NLWP TT       COMMAND         PSR  <-line added
   15     2    15    1 ?        migration/4       4
   16     2    16    1 ?        ksoftirqd/4       4
   17     2    17    1 ?        watchdog/4        4
   31     2    31    1 ?        events/4          4
   46     2    46    1 ?        kintegrityd/4     4
   54     2    54    1 ?        kblockd/4         4
   65     2    65    1 ?        ata/4             4
   88     2    88    1 ?        aio/4             4
   96     2    96    1 ?        crypto/4          4
  420     2   420    1 ?        ext4-dio-unwrit   4
  879     2   879    1 ?        kdmflush          4
  926     2   926    1 ?        ext4-dio-unwrit   4
  935     2   935    1 ?        ext4-dio-unwrit   4
 1632     2  1632    1 ?        rpciod/4          4
```

Comment: I'd recommend against trying to outsmart the Linux scheduler. You're very likely to do more harm than good. Just let it do its thing.

Comment: I guess the threads you see are softirq guys and probably you need to change IRQ SMP affinity mask to make them move to dedicated core. See IRQ-affinity.txt for more info: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt

Comment: @Dan: I edited the the question to include threads still running on core 4. I at least one marked `ksoftirqd`. Can you comment on the others?

Answer (score 2):

Some kernel threads were bound to their special (logic)CPU to do some work related that CPU, You can't migrate those kernel threads from their CPU. What you can do is migrating and pinning all the other tasks.

I guess this strange requirement is not your final purpose, and this(the title) is not the right approach to your purpose. If you provide your final purpose, guys in the SO can help you.

Comment: I figured some of the threads would be required to run on each CPU. In the edit above, I have included all the process still running on core 4. Can any of these be moved to core 0? Do you have a link to any documentaion describing which threads must absolutely be bound to their CPU?